# grid.bindStore() does not allow Infinite Scrolling - Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I'm using a buffered store/infinite scrolling on a grid I defined in my `view` folder  *without* defining a store.

```
var grid = Ext.define('MyApp.view.metadata.ResultGrid' ,{
    extend      : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.resultgrid',
    id          : 'mygrid',
    //columns, etc.
```

I then instantiate it on Ext.application with

```
{ xtype: 'resultgrid', width: '85%', hidden: true}
```

Then, in my `controller` I create my `store`...

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId     : 'resultsetstore',
    model       : model,
    buffered    : true,
    pageSize    : itemsPerPage, //50
    autoLoad    : true,
    leadingBufferZone  : 100,
    remoteSort         : true,
    //etc.
```

...then reconfigure my store to the grid within that controller:

```
Ext.getCmp('mygrid').reconfigure(store);
Ext.getCmp('mygrid').show();
```

With this method, the records get loaded to my grid, but those records get limited to the `pageSize` and I lose the infinite scrolling ability.

Everything works fine if I create a random grid right after I create my store within the Controller. However, I want to keep my grid defined in it's own folder and use `xtype` to create it in a specific location in my app (between a mess of panels/components).

This works:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title       : 'Test Data',
    loadMask    : true,
    store       : store,
```

This doesn't:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title       : 'Test Data',
    loadMask    : true,
    //...
});

grid.reconfigure(store)
```

I can't use the first method within my grid definition because the store isn't defined until a User submits a search form.

Is there a way to keep my grid defined in it's own folder, use my store, ***and*** keep infinite scrolling functionality without putting everything into one giant file?

Answer (score 0):

I instantiated my grid right after my store, then added it to the panel I wanted it in.

```
var app = Ext.getCmp('my_container');
app.add({
    xtype: 'resultgrid', width: '85%', region: 'center', height: 400, collapsible: false, store: store
});
```